# how to show 2 lines with different range on nvd3 graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, nvd3.js

I am plotting a line graph using nvd3 library, it plots two lines but there is huge difference in both line values, one line (line 1) have values close to 500 and second line (line 2) have values between 0-1 because of range difference line 2 which have values in 0-1 is shown as flat line close to x-axis though its values are changing.

If I hide line 1 than i see the line 2 properly with variations, how can I show this kind of graph, here is the code and some snap shots :

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                    .width(800).height(420)
                    .margin({left: 100,right:100})  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
                    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
                    .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
                    .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
                    .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
                    .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis
      ;


  chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
      .axisLabel('X-axis');

  chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
      .axisLabel('')
      .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));


  d3.select('#graph-chart svg')    //Select the <svg> element you want to render the chart in.   
      .datum(data)        //Populate the <svg> element with chart data...
      .call(chart);          //Finally, render the chart!

  //Update the chart when window resizes.
  nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update(); });
  return chart;
});
```

Graph with both values here beta is shown as flat line :

[image]

Graph only with beta :

[image]

Edit :

Testing data

```
 {
    "key": "key1",
    "values": [
        [
            1697000000,
            19024000000
        ],
        [
            1764000000,
            19764000000
        ],
        [
            1829000000,
            21496000000
        ],
        [
            2122000000,
            20559000000
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "key": "key2",
    "values": [
        [
            1697000000,
            13530000
        ],
        [
            1764000000,
            41790000
        ],
        [
            1829000000,
            29280000
        ],
        [
            2122000000,
            11050000
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the data, or a sample of it? Would be easier to test possible solutions...

Comment: added some testing data.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a **multiChart** type, which has **two Y axis**.

There seems to be no documentation on the nvd3 website, but you can see a live example here: http://goo.gl/DnLU6S

Also, if you're using AngularJS, check this out:
http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiChart

Answer (score 0):

With nvd3 you may use a log scale for the Y axis. Useful for such kind of series.

Comment: i tried `chart.yScale(d3.scale.log());` but it has no effect on graph and the y values are mapped to log values.

Answer (score 0):

found some thing, normalize all the data you have on y-axis using any one :

```
a'(i) = a(i)/mean(a)
```

or

```
a'(i) = (a(i) - mean(a))/std_dev(a)
```

a is data array.

Then plot the data and denormalize it back using formatter on y - axis while plotting :

```
a(i) = a'(i) * mean(a)    or   a(i) = a'(i) * std_dev(a) + mean(a)

chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
          .axisLabel('')
          .tickFormat(formatter);
```